# Meteor access user email and password

Tags: meteor

Using meteor with accounts and accounts-password packages.
How can I access a user's email and password for basic auth on an external REST api?

Comment: You mean current user? Meteor.user().emails[0].address and password is encrypted so you cannot access it

Comment: @Sindis thanks, just need to add parenthesis: Meteor.user().emails[0].address

Comment: To bad about the password though, I am aware that they are encrypted on the server side but was hoping that the client could access it when logged in.

Comment: You can create another variable in users collection but this will ruin security on your site

Comment: Yeah that doesn't sound like a good idea. Might have to reconsider the auth system on the api side, any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm but you want to check if password is correct or retrieve it from collection?

Comment: I was hoping to retrieve the password (in clear text), that doesn't look to be possible. I'm wondering if there is some kind of single sign on mechanism I could use instead, if a user is logged in on the meteor app then the api should trust them.

Comment: You can make user write his password down to log into some external API like you do with login with fb/g+ etc., I don't know any way aroundt.

Comment: I'm thinking about generating an auth token and passing that to the api instead.